# Can you automate visual studio database project scripts

Tags: database, visual-studio, project, database-project

When you compare schemas manually, it generates an .sql, is there a way to automate that process so from our custom tool we can go "compare schemas between the test database and the project, generate .sql, run it on production server" so the sql changes from the test database are reflected to production database by the tool? Or has to be manual?

Answer (score 0):

Are you really want to execute the script that was just generated on production?
What happen if someone change a procedure in your development and the same procedure was changed also in production (as a critical fix) - or a new index was created in production as a critical fix?

In these cases, the script that will be generated by visual studio will not alert on the conflicts and will generate a script that revert them.

From my experience I want the script that I'm executing on production to be first tested in the stage / uat environment before I run it on production. I also want the tool that generates the script to be aware of changes and understand the nature of them (promote change or protect target = ignore change or abort in case a conflict exists and a manual intervention is required).